# How to edit and insert dynamicaly created form textboxes values to MySQL DB?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, submit

I'm having a bunch of features table in MySQL DB in my PHP project. I'm fetching through php and creating a table with textboxes named by column name and id of record in photos table using code:

`functions.php` Code:

```
function m_html_editPhotos($id) {
$result = "<table class=\"tabelka\" id=\"tbl_photos\"><thead><tr><th>Miniaturka</th><th>Duże zdjęcie</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
$mysqli = m_db_Init();
$qry = "SELECT ID, Img_Min, Img_Nrm FROM tbl_Zdjecie WHERE ID_Grzyb = ?";
if($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare($qry)) {
          $stmt -> bind_param("i", $id);
          mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $img_id, $img_min, $img_nrm);
          $stmt->execute();
          $i =0;
          while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
              $i = $i+1;
              $result .= "<tr><td><!--<label>Link do miniaturki:<label>--><input type=\"text\" class=\"required\" name=\"photo[$i][min]\" value=$img_min></td><td><!--<label>Link do zdjęcia pełnego rozmiaru:</label>--><input type=\"text\" class=\"required\" name=\"photo[$i][nrm]\" value=$img_nrm></td><td style=\"display:none;\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"photo[$i][id]\" value=$img_id /></td></tr>";
          }
          $stmt -> close();      
}
mysqli_close($mysqli);
$result .= "</tbody></table><div class=\"link\" onclick=\"AddPhotoEditRow();\">Dodaj kolejne zdjęcie</div>";
return $result;
}
```

Now what I'd like is to edit photos table iterating through each row of generated as above table with textboxes for thumbnail_url (`img_min`) and full size link (`img_nrm`)
Additionally I'd like to add new ones to the table from dynamically created rows by function AddPhotoEditRow();

`functions.js` Code:

```
function AddPhotoEditRow(){
 $('#tbl_photos > tbody:last').append('<tr><td><input type="text" name="photo[0][min]"></td><td><input type="text" name="photo[0][nrm]"></td><td style=\"display:none;\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"photo[0][id]\" value=\"0\" /></td></tr>');
}
```

`edit.php` Code:

```
include 'functions.php';
if(isset($_POST["change"])) m_db_updateAllFeatures($_GET["id"]);
if (m_db_isAdmin("")){
if (!isset($_GET["id"]) || !is_numeric($_GET["id"]))
    header("Location: ../index.php");
else {
if (isset($_POST["Nazwa_PL"]))
    m_db_UpdateName("PL", $_GET["id"],$_POST["Nazwa_PL"]);
if (isset($_POST["Nazwa_Lac"]))
    m_db_UpdateName("Lac", $_GET["id"],$_POST["Nazwa_Lac"]);
render_edit_body();
    }
}
```

I'd like to iterate somehow through photos links and update existing records by parsing textbox names passed through $_POST, additionally would be good to insert new photo links (that with id=0). I'm setting new rows' id to 0 because I need to distinguish if I'm inserting to table, or updating, right? I've assumed that all `0`-indexed fields should be added, rest of them should be inserted. I might have my conception wrong, if there is a better way to do full functionality to that table "control" then I'm very open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the basics, except

```
$('#tbl_photo snip snip name="photo[0][min]"> snip snip snip
                                    ^---
```

the `0` should not be hardcoded. You're telling php to create an array of 'photo' values in the $_POST array, but then you force the index keys to be 0 for all entries, causing later ones to overwrite earlier ones.

Keep a count in Javascript as to how many of these fields you've inserted, and use that count to increment the index key, e.g.

```
$('#tbl_photo snip snip name="photo[' + i + '][min]"> snip snip snip
```

instead, where `i` is the field count. Then it's a simple matter of:

```
foreach($_POST['photo'] as $i => $photo) {
    echo $photo['min'];
}
```

to get that min value for each photo field.

Comment: I've just edited the first post explaining why there are `0`'s

Answer (score 1):

If you use `0` for all newly created HTML elements, the PHP `$_POST` will contains just the information of **the last** item.

This is my solution using the same approach as yours with a bit of modification, supposed that we have a `form` wrap outside out loop and an array named `$data` contains the seeding information:

PHP code to create the table

```php
// the $data array contains a list of picture object, these object will be updated later.
foreach($data as $num => $row)
{
    echo "<tr>\n";
    echo sprintf("<td><input type='text' name='name[%d]' value='%s' /></td>\n", $num, $row['name']);
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "<tr><td>\n";
echo "<a id='add-item'>Add new item</a>\n";
echo "<input type="hidden" name='num-created' value='0' />";
echo "</td></tr>\n"
```

JavaScript code to add new element (using jQuery)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#add-item').click(function(){
        var currentCreatedNum = $("input[name=num-created]").val() * 1;
        var html = "<tr>";
        html += "<td><input type='text' name='newname["+ (currentCreatedNum + 1) +"]' value='' /></td>";
        html += "</tr>";            
        $("input[name=num-created]").val(currentCreatedNum + 1);
    });
});
```

The PHP code to manipulate the POST request

```php
# check contrains ...

# update old records
foreach($_POST['name'] as $id => $name)
{
    // get information of existing item and update this record

}

# create new record
foreach($_POST['newname'] as $order => $name)
{
    // get information of new item and create a new record

}
```

As you can see, the `name` attribute of manual created elements must be different from the existing one.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding, you're wanting to access each dynamically created table item? You can do this by simply creating a dynamic array. As each new TD element (or whatever element) is generated, make the name like `name=Something[]` (with empty brackets). This will automatically assign each item generated as a member of the array called "Something". You can of course generate key values through a counter as well.

Here's a simplified example from a project I did, where an "Update" button (not shown here) posts back to the same page:

```
echo "<td class='grid'>
<input type='checkbox' name='chkDel[]' />
</td>";
```

Then the PHP would be as follows:

```
if (isset($_POST['chkDel'])) {

    // Make a MySQL Connection
    $con = mysql_connect(host,user,pwd) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("db_name"); 

    $rows = 0;

    foreach($_POST['chkDel'] as $chkdel)  {

        //query to delete post
        $delQuery = "DELETE FROM table WHERE ".$chkdel;

        //run the query 
        mysql_query($delQuery) or die(mysql_error());

        //Get rows affected
        $i = mysql_affected_rows();
        $rows = $rows + $i;
    }

    mysql_close($con);
}
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Any idea how can I distinguish if the array item is to edit and which to insert in your sugestion?

Comment: If you need the option to delete or insert, simply make two checkboxes instead of one, otherwise you'd have to make unique IDs or names to distinguish which is intended to do what.